# Output in Row after reverse

Tags: javascript, arrays

Output I want to row not column:

```
var String = "hello world!";
var length = String.length;

for (i=11; i>=0; i--)
{
  console.log (String[i]);
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: what does `to row not coloum` mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just logging each character in a string in reverse order instead create a new string and log it.

```js
var String = "hello world!";
var length = String.length;
var res='';

for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  res += String[i];
}
console.log(res);

res = '';
// or while loop
while (length--)
  res += String[length];

console.log(res);
```

The more simple way is to use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to generate a reversed single string.

```js
var String = "hello world!";

console.log(
  String.split('').reverse().join('')
)
```

Comment: This question should be duplicated.